# Wrap apostrophes around string?

Tags: php

I'm trying to wrap apostrophes around a string in PHP.

I've shown the result of each step. I can't figure out how to wrap '' around each name?

I can get this far `Listen Up, Case Studies, Publications` but I need the result to look like this `'Listen Up', 'Case Studies', 'Publications'`

```
$categories = $wlrs_cats[0]['content_type']; 

$value = implode(',', $categories);
// $value = content-type/listen-up/,content-type/case-studies/,content-type/publications/

$result = ucwords(strtr($value, ["content-type/"=>" '", "/"=>"'", "-"=>" "]), "' ");
// $result; // 'Listen Up', 'Case Studies', 'Publications'
```

Comment: What does the original string look like?

Comment: Like this: content-type/listen-up/,content-type/case-studies/,content-type/publications/

Comment: explode the `$names_uc` string around `","`, then implode it with `"', '"` with a leading and trailing `'`

Comment: `"'" . implode("', '", explode(", ", $names_uc)) . "'"`

Comment: Why explode it right after imploding it, @Pierre? The very first step he does is imploding the string.

Comment: @zbee the implode and explode statements are not with the same "glue" parameter !

Comment: @Pierre I've edited my original post, your suggestion works... but something further up adds a space after the first apostrophe?

Comment: maybe there are leading/trailing spaces here and there in your strings. shouldn't do that with the code provided (used many times on my projects when dealing with similar use cases of strings with delimiters). The `explode` statement only removes 1 space after the comma. If there are more than 1 they will stay in the string... Maybe you should apply a `trim` on the exploded array to be sure

Comment: Maybe I was not clear : "you should apply a `trim` on the exploded array" means you have to call `trim` on each array value (there are PHP function to do the iteration, don't write a for loop !)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would propose a simpler solution, where `$string` is your original like `content-type/listen-up/,content-type/case-studies/,content-type/publications/`:

```
$result = ucwords(strtr($string, ["content-type/"=>" '", "/"=>"'", "-"=>" "]), "' ");
```

So you replace certain things and then capitalize stating what words are followed by (`'` and `space`).

Comment: This would also reduce the operations OP is performing on the string.

Comment: This works great! I've updated the original post. +1

Answer (score 1):

I believe the best approach would be to add these apostrophes in while it's still in array, just before your first `implode` operation.

You could get a little bit fancy, and walk the array, adding the apostrophes, like so:

```
$categories = $wlrs_cats[0]['content_type'];
array_walk($categories, function(&$value) {
  $value = "'$value'";
});
//Returns: 'content-type/listen-up/','content-type/case-studies/','content-type/publications/'
```

Or more simply, you could `foreach` over the array and apply it in the same manner:

```
$categories = $wlrs_cats[0]['content_type'];
foreach ($categories as &$value)
  $value = "'$value'";
//Returns: 'content-type/listen-up/','content-type/case-studies/','content-type/publications/'
```

Comment: How does the comma get inserted? Never mind ... on the implied `implode()`. Your solution also has the advantage of being able to handle commas correctly within a "content-type".

Comment: Right, this does assume this is the first step, I'll clarify that. While not explicitly necessary, there is that advantage, yes

Comment: First example works great +1, just trying to get it to work with the rest of the code :)

Comment: @StephenMeehan You should be able to replace this line in your code with either of my examples: `$categories = $wlrs_cats[0]['content_type'];`